# Async call within Async call not executed

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurlsession

I'm trying to retrieve the XML from an rss feed, get the links for each article, and then extract info from those articles. I'm using [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) to get the xml, and [ReadabilityKit](https://github.com/exyte/ReadabilityKit) for link extraction.

I'm successfully pulling the links from the XML, but the parser call on Readability is never executing. I don't want this on the main thread as it blocks all UI, but so far that's the only way I've made it work. Code is below (removed that dispatch get main queue):

```
func retrieveXML() {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "<XML URL HERE>")!)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if data == nil {
            print("\n\ndataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let xmlDoc = try AEXMLDocument(xmlData: data!)
            for child in xmlDoc.root.children {

                if let postURL = child["id"].value {

                    let url = NSURL(string: postURL)
                    let parser = Readability(url: url!)
                    let title = parser.title()
                    print("TITLE: \(title)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? 
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let url = NSURL(string: postURL)
    let parser = Readability(url: url!)
    let title = parser.title()
    print("TITLE: \(title)")
}`

Comment: @heikomania that doesn't compile =/. However, if I puth the "parser = Readability..." line in the main queue, it blocks the UI, which I don't want.

Comment: Yeah, that's Swift 3 and dispatching to the main queue, but the concept is right: `Readability` is deadlocking so you have to dispatch it asynchronously to another queue. But, I agree, that you shouldn't use the main queue for that. And, of course, if you're using Swift 2, then use Swift 2 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting. The new version is available in cocoa pods and cartage with a new aync API. Sync API is removed from the project.

```
Readability.parse(url: articleUrl, { data in
  let title = data?.title
  let description = data?.description
  let keywords = data?.keywords
  let imageUrl = data?.topImage
  let videoUrl = data?.topVideo
})
```

Thanks for your contribution! For more info please check README https://github.com/exyte/ReadabilityKit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Readability` is deadlocking. You're calling it from a `NSURLSession` completion block (which defaults to a serial queue), but `Readability` blocks that queue with a semaphore until its own network request is completed. So `Readability` is deadlocking because it's blocking a thread waiting for a semaphore signal that is supposed to be sent from the same thread it is blocking.

You can fix this by asynchronously dispatching the code that instantiates `Readability` to a separate queue (e.g. a global queue).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)) {
    let url = NSURL(string: postURL)
    let parser = Readability(url: url!)
    let title = parser.title()
    print("TITLE: \(title)")
}
```

---

It looks like that API has been updated to run asynchronously, so get the latest version and this deadlocking issue is eliminated and the above asynchronous dispatch will not be needed. You'll obviously have to employ the completion handler pattern of the updated API.